# Pure Data from print~ to print second element with print

Tags: puredata

[image]

With the following program, I get a big list out of `print~`.

I want to a get the second value from this list.

How to get this second value and print it with print and not `print~`?

Comment: Sorry but I am not able to understand your question at all, could you please try to formulate it better? I am also not a native speaker, but phrases like "have do a get ..." or "out have to get" make absolutely no sense at all.

Answer (score 0):

`[print~]` will always print the entire signal-block (in your case 128 values).

to get a specific sample, you could instead use a table, feed the monitored signal into it, and retrieve the value(s) you are interested:

```
...
|
[tabsend~ $0-foo]

[table $0-foo 128]

[2(
|
[tabread $0-foo]
|
[print]
```

note: unlike with `[print~]`, which will only generate output at the *next* signal block, this will output the data immediately (that is: it will take the signal data from the *last* signal block).
to get the *next* signal-block, you can replace the lower part of the suggested solution with something like the following:

```
[bang~]            [2(
|                  |
|      [r $0-next] |
|      |           |
[spigot]           [t b       f]
|                  |           |
[t f b]            [1(         |
|     |            |           |
|     [0(          [s $0-next] |
|     |                        |
|     [s $0-next]              |
|                              |
[float                         ]
|
[tabread $0-foo]
|
...
```

(the patch uses `[s/r $0-next]` to avoid cross-over connection lines in the ascii graphics; in practice you probably want to use straight connections instead)
it's probably best to encapsulate the entire thing into an abstraction.